# Converting a string list to integer in swi prolog as shown

Tags: lambda, prolog

How to convert a string list to integers? Eg: if the list is ['i','am','fine'], the result should be [9,14,34]  (i=9,am=1+13=14,fine=6+9+14+5=34)

How do I do this in SWI Prolog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program can be built with a single built-in predicate, [`atom_codes`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_codes/2) and the standard recursion facilities of the language.

You need two rules - one to transform a list item-by-item to another list, and another one to total up the codes from which an atom is composed.

Each rule would have two parts - one to process the base case (i.e. an empty list), and one to reduce the incoming list by one item.

Here is a sample implementation with a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/uaHb1d):

```
sum_atoms([], []).
sum_atoms([H|T], [HeadSum|RT]) :-
    atom_codes(H, Codes),
    sum_letters(Codes, HeadSum),
    sum_atoms(T, RT).

sum_letters([], 0).
sum_letters([H|T], Res) :-
    sum_letters(T, TailSum),
    Res is (H-96) + TailSum.
```

If you would like to use [`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist%2F2) and [`sumlist/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sumlist/2), built-in predicates for list processing, you can shorten your program like this:

```
sum_atoms(In, Out) :-
    maplist(sum_letters, In, Out).

sum_letters(Atom, Sum) :-
    atom_codes(Atom, Codes),
    maplist(plus(-96), Codes, LetterNumbers),
    sumlist(LetterNumbers, Sum).
```

[Link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/OK4vWs).

Answer (score 1):

If you have module lambda (http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you can write

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

convert(Lst, Val) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(atom_codes(X, Ch),
              foldl(\Z^T^U^(U is T + Z-96),Ch, 0, Y)), Lst, Val).
```

Comment: on doing so, i get the following error :  ERROR: apply:maplist_/3: Undefined procedure: (\)/3
   Exception: (9) \(_G1350^_G1353^ (atom_codes(_G1350, _G1360), foldl(\_G1369^_G1372^_G1375^ (...is...), _G1360, 0, _G1353)), i, _G1390) ?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your version of SWI-Prolog ? Mine is 6.3.11 for Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: @User111213: What does `maplist(=,[A],L)` respond?

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(Atoms, Values) :-
    maplist(a2n, Atoms, Values).

a2n(Atom, Num) :-
    atom_codes(Atom, Cs),
    [A] = "a",
    maplist(sub(A), Cs, L),
    sumlist(L, Num).

sub(A, C, N) :- N is C - A + 1.
```